# Why does a cast from floating point to integer truncate?

Tags: c++, floating-point, rounding

In C and C++, we all know that converting a floating point value into an integer performs a *truncation*. That means, a fix *towards zero*, both for `static_cast` and for C style casts.

```
static_assert(static_cast<int>(2.9) == 2);
static_assert((int)-3.7 == -3);
```

To convert a floating point number into an integer, there are 4 options, each of them is implemented by a standard function from `<cmath>`:

1. `round`
2. `floor`
3. `ceil`
4. `trunc`

I ordered the options from the most often used to the least often used, from my own experience (it is somewhat subjective).

Truncation toward zero means that all values from -0.999... to 0.999... are converted to 0. There is a for that reason a mathematical anomaly near 0, which makes truncation rarely useful. My impression is that nearly every time a programmer directly casts a floating point to an integer, he actually wants `floor`, but can afford `trunc` behavior because the value is supposed to be always positive.

My question is: what were the motivations to select the 4th option, truncate? I bet this is mostly historical, but when C was originally developed, there must have been some good reason to select truncation over the more useful rounding or flooring.

Comment: Probably because that's the operation of the CPU instruction that converts from float to int. On modern x86 that would be `cvttss2si`. I'm not aware of any instruction in the cvt set that performs any other form of rounding, you can see all of them [here](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/intrinsics-guide/index.html#techs=SSE,SSE2,SSE3,SSSE3,SSE4_1,SSE4_2,AVX,AVX2&text=ss2si). This is also probably mandated by IEEE754.

Comment: As usual in C and C++, default operations should be efficient; expensive operations should be explicit.

Comment: Re: "makes truncation rarely useful" -- I rarely use anything else.

Comment: @PeteBecker Yes. But is truncating really faster than rounding? On modern hardware, I am pretty sure it is not the case. Maybe on old hardware.

Comment: @prapin -- does "pretty sure" mean you're guessing, or that you have facts to support it? (I don't know one way or the other)

Comment: @prapin Yes, rounding is slower, for SSE rounding `round`, `ceil`, and `floor` all have a latency of 8, and only return a float, the convert instruction has a latency between 4 and 7 depending on hardware revision.

Comment: It's not `truncate` it's `trunc`. And it does not cast to integer, it's a floating point to floating point call.

Comment: Since floating point values are represented by sign bit, exponent and fraction truncating can be done by simply doing a bit shift on the fraction and modifying the exponent, so it's the easiest one of those operations to implement (whether in hardware as multiple processor instructions by the compiler should the instruction set not provide this functionality)...

Comment: @Jellyboy Oh, you are right, I should have checked. I edited the function accordingly.

Comment: @fabian That looks like a very good reason. Maybe the real one actually.

Comment: How would you expect to produce an integral value from a floating point value if it didn't truncate (or do some other type of rounding)?

Comment: Re “there are 4 options”: [There are at least thirteen.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Rounding_to_integer) And they are missing round-to-odd (if the fraction is non-zero, round to make the integer odd), which is useful for preserving information to avoid errors caused by double-rounding.

Comment: @Peter Of course, we need some rounding. My point is that it would have been more useful to round down or round to nearest than toward zero.

Comment: @prapin - From a language perspective, one has to be picked - and whatever choice is made (as you are demonstrating) some folks will complain about and others will find useful. The specification of "round toward zero" is consistent with how operations on integral types now work (integer division rounds toward zero rather than up or down) [before 1999 the rounding mode was unspecified for negative values]. Historically (e.g. 1970s) floating support in C was a bit of an afterthought, so the spec was based on common hardware rather than any deep thought about merits of different rounding modes.

Answer (score 4):

You use it when you want to floor the modulus of the value irrespective of the sign. This can happen for multiple reasons that are particular to every application. You might have it in Physics, Finance, Engineering, etc.

On x86_64, `trunc(float)` is mapped to the [`roundss` instruction on glibc](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/sysdeps/x86_64/fpu/multiarch/s_truncf-sse4_1.S.html)

```
ENTRY(__truncf_sse41)
        roundss        $11, %xmm0, %xmm0
        ret
END(__truncf_sse41)
```

The constant $11 above, it's an immediate operand to the actual instruction and determines the rounding characteristics.  That particular instruction contain the choices you mentioned (see [Intel Intrinsics Guide](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/intrinsics-guide/index.html#text=mm_round_ss&ig_expand=5924)) :

```
__m128 _mm_round_ss (__m128 a, __m128 b, int rounding)
Synopsis
__m128 _mm_round_ss (__m128 a, __m128 b, int rounding)
#include <smmintrin.h>
Instruction: roundss xmm, xmm, imm8
CPUID Flags: SSE4.1
Description
Round the lower single-precision (32-bit) floating-point element in b using the rounding parameter, store the result as a single-precision floating-point element in the lower element of dst, and copy the upper 3 packed elements from a to the upper elements of dst.
Rounding is done according to the rounding[3:0] parameter, which can be one of:
    (_MM_FROUND_TO_NEAREST_INT |_MM_FROUND_NO_EXC) // round to nearest, and suppress exceptions
    (_MM_FROUND_TO_NEG_INF |_MM_FROUND_NO_EXC)     // round down, and suppress exceptions
    (_MM_FROUND_TO_POS_INF |_MM_FROUND_NO_EXC)     // round up, and suppress exceptions
    (_MM_FROUND_TO_ZERO |_MM_FROUND_NO_EXC)        // truncate, and suppress exceptions
    _MM_FROUND_CUR_DIRECTION // use MXCSR.RC; see _MM_SET_ROUNDING_MODE
```

So this is by no means a language choice, it's a demand from users.